# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams

Tags: android, classcastexception

I m working on slide show.Slide show is working but when i move image forward or backward with my hand the app crashed and giving such error

```
"06-09 12:23:45.911:  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.Gallery$LayoutParams"
Got a ClassCastException in onLayout most likely caused by a racecondition in the mRecycle bin "
```

i am using media router it always give me warning that media router cann't be initiated.
That's my media router code

```
MenuItem mediaRouteItem = menu.findItem( R.id.menuChromecast );
            android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton = (android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton) mediaRouteItem.getActionView();
return true;
```

Comment: can you post your menu.xml file and the method in which you are initializing menu item.

Comment: <item
    android:id="@+id/menuChromecast"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_chromecast"/>

Comment: Cannot instantiate class: android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException